# How to call internal function on deployed smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, nft, solidity-0.8.x

I'm deliving into NFTs and smart contracts

I've deployed a simple NFT contract as a test usiing OpenZeppelin and Remix and the token Burn function is internal - if I, as the owner and creator of the contract, want to burn tokens - how am I able to do this? What is the code required in another smart contract required in order to access the internal burn function?

I've read through other similar threads and other resources but I'm struggling to figure it out.

As an aside - once a token is burned, am I able to re-mint the SAME tokenId and also, if that token is no longer owned by me, would I be able to burn it as the contract owner?

In summary, how would a developer/creator of an NFT undo mistakes in minting/creating an NFT with the contract as written below. Thanks.

Code in solidity:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    uint256 public constant MAX_TOKENS = 5000;
    
    uint256 public constant MAX_TOKENS_PER_PURCHASE = 10;

    uint256 private price = 1000000000000000; // 0.001 Ether

    bool public isSaleActive = true;
    
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("MyNFT", "NFT") {}

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "ipfs://[IPFSHash]/";
    }

    function safeMint(uint256 _amount, address to) public onlyOwner {
    for(uint256 i = 0; i < _amount; i++){
        _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
    }
}
    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you need to add a public brun function in your MyNft contract and that function can only be called by owner and that public function call the internal function..

Comment: no internal functions cannot be called from outside the contarct.. if a token is minted then it will stay for ever. What you only can do is to force (in real life) the owner of that nft to clear approvals and then send it to the zero address. (I think that is actually what the burn function do) https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L302

Comment: In fact, the code of your `_burn()` function is likely not even present on chain. The compiler does not generate code for internal functions that are never called - exactly because there's no way for anyone to call them by issuing a transaction.